# How do I delete the least recently accessed key in an associative array?

Tags: d

I have an associative array limited to x amount of keys and want to remove the least recently accessed key in order to add another. I found HashAA in mintl which would be able to do the job in D1 but I've found nothing for D2. Is there anything that supports this now or would I need to maintain a second array to get the job done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a real answer but I thought it would be fun to try and implement it in a few minutes (it's probably very inefficient and maybe buggy):

```
import std.stdio;
import std.traits;

struct MyHash(AA, size_t Limit)
    if (isAssociativeArray!AA)
{
    alias KeyType!AA Key;
    alias ValueType!AA Value;

    void opIndexAssign(Value value, Key key)
    {
        if (hash.length >= Limit)
        {
            Key leastUsed = leastUsedKey;
            hash.remove(leastUsed);
            counts.remove(leastUsed);
        }

        hash[key] = value;
    }

    Value opIndex(Key key)
    {
        counts[key]++;
        return hash[key];
    }

    Value[Key] hash;
    alias hash this;

private:

    @property Key leastUsedKey()
    {
        Key result;
        size_t maxCount = size_t.max;

        foreach (key; hash.byKey)
        {
            if (auto count = key in counts)
            {
                if (*count < maxCount)
                {
                    maxCount = *count;
                    result = key;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return key;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    size_t[Key] counts;
}

// just to avoid declaring variables in main()
@property void consume(int key) { }

void main()
{
    MyHash!(int[int], 3) hash;

    hash[0] = 0;
    hash[1] = 0;
    hash[2] = 0;

    writeln(hash.keys);

    hash[2].consume;
    hash[5] = 0;

    writeln(hash.keys); // 2 stays, 5 added

    hash.clear();
    hash[0] = 0;
    hash[1] = 0;
    hash[2] = 0;

    hash[0].consume;
    hash[1].consume;
    hash[1].consume;
    hash[2].consume;
    hash[2].consume;
    hash[2].consume;

    hash[5] = 0;
    writeln(hash);  // (0 removed)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The built in AAs will rehash when they need to in order to fit more elements, are not fixed in size, and will not keep track of how you've accessed or added elements, and because the language has AAs built in, alternate hash table implementations are going to be relatively rare (most everyone just uses the built in AAs).

So, I'm pretty darn sure that you would need to do this yourself - probably by creating a wrapper around the built in AA type and having the wrapper keep track of all of the accesses to it so that it knows which key was accessed least recently.

You could always check out [dcollections](http://dsource.org/projects/dcollections) for some alternate container implemenations (and IIRC it *does* have a hash table in it, but I doubt that it does what you want). Personally, I've never even *heard* of a hash table that acted the way that you want it to, so I expect that what you're looking for is at least somewhat abnormal. But it should be simple enough to create a wrapper around AAs which acts the way that you want.

Comment: remove the least-recently-used value on add is standard cache behavior